# Text Array not producing Quotes in Text Box

Tags: vb.net

I have a simple text generator but the following code is not producing Quotes for the text in the TextBox, it is just the text without quotes. Thoughts?

```
TextBox1.Text = RAND("" & rng.Next(RAND.Count()) & "")
```

I have also tried this but no quotes showing..

```
TextBox1.Text = ("" & RAND(rng.Next(RAND.Count())) & "")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't add quotes to the output. `""` is just an empty string. You need to add the quote in the string and escape it (with another double quote).

This code should be ok:

```
TextBox1.Text = """" & RAND(rng.Next(RAND.Count())) & """"
' or
TextBox1.Text = String.Format("""{0}""", RAND(rng.Next(RAND.Count())))
```

Comment: @CJSoldier: As a side note, you could declare a constant called DOUBLE_QUOTE = `""""`, to avoid counting double quotes.

Comment: Thanks Neolisk. I will try that. I am sure that will become helpful if my list grows in size.